# Plotting with matplotlib specgram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, spectrogram

I'm trying to plot a signal and the spectrogram of the signal with matplotlib, but... i get the spectrogram only for the first value (samples) of my signal (like 60 of the 30000...).

It's a very long file, that's why I would like to plot only the first 30000 sample.

here is the code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Data=pd.read_csv('MySignal.txt', 
    skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19], 
    header=0)
print(Data.head())
DataI=Data['Sig'].tolist()
print(len(Data.index))
DataI=DataI[0:30000]

NFFT = 200     # the length of the windowing segments
Fs = 500  # the sampling rate

# plot signal and spectrogram

t=range(len(DataI))
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t, DataI)
plt.subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(DataI, NFFT=NFFT, 
                        Fs=Fs,noverlap=100, cmap=plt.cm.gist_heat)
plt.show()
```

I don't understand well how plt.specgram work, so i don't understand where is the problem...

Thanks a lot !

Comment: It would help if you gave an executable example, e.g. with some synthetic data. Just something simple like an upchirp or a few sines with different frequencies.  That would also be the best way to troubleshoot since you separate your (possibly undersampled) data from your analysis.

Comment: Very likely there is a sampling rate problem, since you generate your time as [0,1,2,3...] which is likely seconds, but you use a sampling rate of 500. So try dividing t by 1000 or so.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I couldn't test it... now appear a MemoryError (seems to stop line 7, "header 0")... I do not understand why...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here a quick and dirty synthetic example of three tones an octave apart each, which works fine. Please read up on the sampling theorem to understand the idea of a spectrogram. It's actually best to first learn how to plot spectra (vertical slices of the spectrogram) by just playing with FFTs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

time1 = np.arange(0,5,0.0001)
time = np.arange(0,15,0.0001)
data1=np.sin(2*np.pi*300*time1)
data2=np.sin(2*np.pi*600*time1)
data3=np.sin(2*np.pi*900*time1)
data=np.append(data1,data2 )
data=np.append(data,data3)
print len(time)
print len(data)

NFFT = 200     # the length of the windowing segments
Fs = 500  # the sampling rate

# plot signal and spectrogram

ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(time,data)   # for this one has to either undersample or zoom in 
plt.xlim([0,15])
plt.subplot(212 )  # don't share the axis
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(data, NFFT=NFFT,   Fs=Fs,noverlap=100, cmap=plt.cm.gist_heat)
plt.show()
```

The top x-axis is in seconds.I zoomed in at the transition of 300 Hz to 600 Hz at 5 seconds for clarity. The bottom axis is not in seconds, which is why I took out the sharing of the axes. That can be fixed (detail). 
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help,