# Calculating power-spectrogram on a window of a .wav file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, signal-processing

I am trying to calculate the power-spectrogram of a part of a soundfile.
Currently I am using [librosa](http://bmcfee.github.io/librosa/) for this.

I am calculating my windowsize by 20*1e-3*samplerate. 
What I am wondering about is the result (specifically the length of t) as can be seen in the example below:

A samplerate of 44.1kHz combined with the timeframe of 20ms yields a window of 882 samples.

```
In [2]: D = np.abs(librosa.stft(y[:882]))**2

In [3]: np.shape(D)
Out[4]: (1025, 2)
```

What I get is a 2ms timeframe in my result, which is not what I expected. Can somebody help me / point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please try to give a [MCVE] . Maybe add a plot of what you get, vs what you expected. It is often a good idea to start with some synthetic data, that you understand. Take a look at this spectrogram question e.g  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932145/plotting-with-matplotlib-specgram/35933996#35933996

Comment: you do realize that "20ms*1e-3" is 20 _micro_-seconds, right?

Comment: Ah, yes - I got it right in my code but somehow labeled it wrong in my example. It is of course 20sec * 1e-3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default [`librosa.stft`](https://bmcfee.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.stft.html) uses an FFT size `n_fft` of 2048 and the first dimension of the output matches the number of non-redundant frequency components for real input signals (which is `1+n_fft/2`, in this case 1025).

The second dimension is determined by the number of time slices, and I assume this is where you are getting a little puzzled, expecting a single time slice from your 882 samples. However [`librosa.stft`](https://bmcfee.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.stft.html) computes output for *overlapping* time slices. The number of samples used for each of these slices is by default set to `win_length / 4` which, since you didn't specify `win_length`, is set to `n_fft / 4` or 512. Making full use of your 882 samples (and padding as needed), this gives you two slices:

- one for samples 0 to 2047;
- another for samples 512 to 881, and added zero padding.

If you do not want any overlapping, you may set the `hop_length` argument to match `n_fft`.

Comment: Reading this again, shouldn't I get two slices: 0 to 511 and 512 to 881 + padding?

Comment: The size of the slices are based on the `n_ffft` parameter, which is by default 2048. Hence the first slice uses samples 0 to 2047. The second slice overlaps the first, starting at 512 and would end at 2559 (but since you don't have that much data uses your samples up to sample 881, then zero pad to a length of 2048).

Comment: Okay , sorry for coming back at this again, but maybe you can help - considering I got multiple files with a range of samplerates betweeen ~10kHz - 500khz on which I would like to build mfccs with a fixed window length of 20 seconds. These mfccs need to be of the same shape so I can feed them to a neural net. Would it be better to add more slices filled with zeros or to upscale the hop-length (I assume with a factor of highest_samplerate/current_samplerate)?

Comment: Not sure either approach will achieve what you'd like. Adding entire slices of zeros (time domain samples) will produce spectrum slices with zero amplitudes which is likely going to throw off you neural net. Skipping samples by increasing the hop-length on the other hand would presumably mean not using lots of valuable input data. Not to mention that if you use the same value of `n_fft` you would be looking at bins which correspond to different frequencies for files with different sampling rates. Instead I'd pad the frequency spectrums to get the same shape.